# Can Firebase accept SOAP messages

Tags: database, parsing, soap, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This may be the wrong way to phrase this, however I'll ask none the less.

Can I code a Firebase database to accept and parse SOAP protocol messages into my database?

I am new to databases in general, aside from sql, and am just trying to make sure I start off on the right footing.

I will be displaying my Firebase database entries to a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All SDKs and APIs to access the Firebase Database are [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). At the moment that does not include a SOAP API.

It is unlikely that such an API will be added (definitely not in the near future). You could try searching if somebody has made a bridge, but I don't recall every hearing of one.